# Get the value of textbox and set to table cell

Tags: jquery

i created at the table row at the runtime and one of the table column contain the textbox . I would like to get the value of the textbox and set the value of textbox to particular table column. The column Gute contains the textbox. I can the get the value of the each textbox but when try to add the particular textbox to table column it`s adding to all the other columns.

```
$('#detaildata').on('change', '#gult', function() {
$(this).hide();
pos=$(this).val();
$('#detailtablerows #gulttextbox').append(pos);

});
```

Comment: What does your table look like? and your text value?

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ and it may useful to explain your problem

Comment: htmldata="<tr id='detailtablerows'><td  id='gulttextbox'><input type='text' name='glut' value='' id='gult' /></td>"+"<td>"+grundlagedata.anbieter+"</td>"+"<td>"+grundlagedata.netz+"</td>"+"<td>"+grundlagedata.name+"</td>"+"<td>"+grundlagedata.code+"</td>"+"<td>"+grundlagedata.kosten+"</td>"+"<td></td></tr>";
       $("#show #detaildata").append(htmldata);  
} );

Comment: I would like to know how can i get the value from each textbox inside the table column and add the value of the textbox to the corresponding table column

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you have multiple elements with the same `id`, they must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending elements with the same `id`, they must be unique. I suggest you change them to classes, and then you can do the following:-

```
$('#detaildata').on('change', '.gult', function() {
    $(this).hide().parent().text(this.value);   
});
```